# VB.net: MS Access- Problems in adding records second time without closing debug application?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I developed a windows application using VB.net with MS Access DB. I am facing one problem while adding records second time/more. My first add, it added one time in DB correctly. While Adding new record second time, it added two times.
While third add, previous records added in place of new. After completing i saw my db, it looks like that (it just an example, not my db because its too big)

```
jo 18 USA 15000             //first records
ji 19 UAE 12000             //second record  
ji 19 UAE 12000             //extra second record   
ji 19 UAE 12000             //second record in place third
```

Here is my add code:

```
Public Class GPE_Addstaff
    Dim db As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.accdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Private Sub addnew_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles addnew.Click
        If empname.Text <> "" And addressline1.Text <> "" And addressline2.Text <> "" And city.Text <> "" And pincode.Text <> "" And phone.Text <> "" And email.Text <> "" And designation.Text <> "" And empid.Text <> "" And salary.Text <> "" And workingdays.Text <> "" And pf.Text <> "" And esi.Text <> "" And netpay.Text <> "" And bankname.Text <> "" And accountno.Text <> "" And salary.Text <> "" Then
            db.Open()
            cmd.Connection = db
            cmd.CommandText = "select *from staffdetails where [employee_ID]='" & empid.Text & "' "
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds)
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
                cmd.Connection = db
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into staffdetails values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n,@o,@p)"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", empname.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", addressline1.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("c", addressline2.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", city.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("e", pincode.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f", phone.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("g", email.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("h", designation.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("i", empid.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("j", salary.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("k", workingdays.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("l", pf.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("m", esi.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("n", netpay.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("o", bankname.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", accountno.Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("New staff database Added successfully")
                ds.Clear()
                da.Dispose()
                db.Close()
                empname.Text = ""
                addressline1.Text = ""
                addressline2.Text = ""
                phone.Text = ""
                email.Text = "           @   .com"
                empid.Text = ""
                salary.Text = 0
                esi.Text = 0
                pf.Text = 0
                netpay.Text = 0
                bankname.Text = ""
                accountno.Text = "AC000000000"
            Else
                MsgBox("Employee_ID already exists")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("please fill all the details")
        End If
        db.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't declare a single command at the class level.  Create the command inside the method and create two separate commands for the SELECT and the INSERT.

Comment: Thank you it works............